# ConnectionStrings not working when I publish solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I publish my project I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'serverusername'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString

The reason why Im getting the error is cause I'm using windowns authentication for that connectionString. It works well in my local machine but when I publish different server that has that site it gives me that error. It should be using windowns authentication because this is not the first app I have publish on that server, so I dont understand why when it connects to that server 'thisserver' it doesn't connect with the correct windowns authentication.

```
 <add name="wfserver" 
      connectionString="Server=thisserver;Database=thisdatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
//     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wfserver"].ToString()))
{

   "select * from mytable where year = @yearnumber ";

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
    sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearnumber", year);


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    List<workflowMonthly> modelList = new List<workflowMonthly>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var model = new workflowMonthly()
        {
            WorkflowName = row["WorkflowName"].ToString(),
            ...
        };

        modelList.Add(model);
    }

    return modelList;
}
```

I have a form and the issue happens after I click submit and looks for the data

View:

```
  @User.Identity.Name (shows correct windows authentication)

  @using (Html.BeginForm("page", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "commentForm", role = "form" }))

 {}
```

Comment: stupid question, but have you checked if "serverusername" has access to the db? it's surely not the same user that you're using on your local machine.  what's your web server?

Comment: You must give access to the IIS App Pool on `thisdatabase` the user would be `IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName` change `AppPoolName` to the real application pool name that runs your application

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing the site local? If so then what ever you are using to access SQL Server from SSMS you should not be have a problem. If you are publishing to another location then I would create a dbname and password and replace you Webconfig CnnectionString.

In shorts create a sa like account and password. Try something like this.
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"